# Подключить PDcurses к проекту. Cmakelist + статическая библиотека

Tags: c++, cmake

Не могу подключить PDcurses к C++ проекту. После компиляции мы получаем файлы `panel.a`, `pdcurses.a` и `curses.h`. Как присоединить их к проекту, чтобы, наконец, избавиться от ошибки

> undefined reference to function

Я пробовал несколько вариантов вызова различных функций в **CMake.txt**, но ни один вариант не подошёл. Требуется решение проблемы именно используя Cmake.txt - это был бы самый правильный выход.

*Исходное содержание CMake.txt:*

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(RogueLike)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(RogueLike ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Версия CMake: 3.6, IDE: CLion от JetBrains

Comment: @alexolut, насколько я вижу, в вашем вопросо-ответе не раскрыта тема внесения изменений в конфигурацию генератора *cmake*, поэтому данный вопрос нельзя считать дубликатом указанного вами.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin как прилинковать через `cmake` действительно не сказано, но проблема именно в отсутствии указания линковщику нужной библиотеки. В любом случае, переголосовать по дубликату я уже не могу, только если отменив свой голос на закрытие вовсе.